# How do I add ajax callback to a form element which is created in a foreach loop

Tags: 8, ajax

Please see the following code:

```
foreach ($formaddresses as $key => $val) {
  // Add edit buttons to custom client-side created addresses.
  if (!isset($val['accountnumber'])) {
    $form['orderinfo']['billshipaddresses']['billingaddresses'][$key]['#description'] = '<a class="edit-stored-address edit-stored-address-target-' . $key . '">Edit</a>';
    $form['orderinfo']['billshipaddresses']['shippingaddresses'][$key]['#description'] = '<a class="edit-stored-address edit-stored-address-target-' . $key . '">Edit</a>';
  }
}
```

Here this loop is creating some anchors in my form.
I just need to **attach/add '#ajax' callback** to it.
How can I achieve this?

Something like the following code:

```
$form['orderinfo']['billshipaddresses']['shippingaddresses'] = [
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => 'Shipping Address',
  '#options' => $formaddressesOptions,
  '#default_value' => '',
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::buildShipBillAddresses',
    'wrapper' => 'shippingaddresses',
    'event' => 'change'
  ],
];
```

Here we can see if the above radio is change then an ajax callback will work and will call this method **buildShipBillAddresses**
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the anchor element to which you want to add an AJAX callback isn't a form element. The [Ajax API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/ajax/8.9.x) page says how to trigger AJAX for a link.

> Add class 'use-ajax' to a link. The link will be loaded using an Ajax call. When using this method, the href of the link can contain '/nojs/' as part of the path. When the Ajax JavaScript processes the page, it will convert this to '/ajax/'. The server is then able to easily tell if this request was made through an actual Ajax request or in a degraded state, and respond appropriately.

This means that for a link, the following code would work.

```php
foreach ($formaddresses as $key => $val) {
  // Add edit buttons to custom client-side created addresses.
  if (!isset($val['accountnumber'])) {
    $form['orderinfo']['billshipaddresses']['billingaddresses'][$key]['#description'] = '<a href="/nojs/edit-billing-address" class="use-ajax edit-stored-address edit-stored-address-target-' . $key . '">Edit</a>';
    $form['orderinfo']['billshipaddresses']['shippingaddresses'][$key]['#description'] = '<a href="/nojs/edit-shipping-address" class="use-ajax edit-stored-address edit-stored-address-target-' . $key . '">Edit</a>';
  }
}
```

The module needs to define two routes for those links. I cannot tell you the code for those route callbacks, but they should render the *Edit* form to make it appear on that form.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Drupal question so much as a PHP question, but to answer your question:

```
foreach ($formaddresses as $key => $val) {
  // Add edit buttons to custom client-side created addresses.
  if (!isset($val['accountnumber'])) {
    $form['orderinfo']['billshipaddresses']['billingaddresses'][$key]['#ajax'] = [
      'callback' => '::buildShipBillAddresses',
      'wrapper' => 'shippingaddresses',
      'event' => 'change'
    ];
  }
}
```